# Fast save/search update which database to use redis vs solr

Tags: solr, redis, sms-gateway, smpp

Hello I have a project of implementing a smpp client which would connect to various telcos like a client aggregator to handle like 16 binds for each of the 5 SMSCs we currently. This will be either based on java or python (have not decided yet).

I am contemplating using a save and forward mode where messages sent by applications behind the smpp client would be stored (for billing and auditing purpose) and then looked up for update when smsc returns updates.

I have read about redis a while ago and it seems adequate for my scenario in terms of fast write. If my message Ids are my keys, would search and update of messages status be done nicely as well in redis?

I have also read about search capability of solr which would be nice for auditing/operation and some basic csv reporting.

It would be nice if anybody who has worked with both make a suggestion on which fits the most per my intended usage described here. I am also open to any other aside mongoDB(sensible default).

Thanks

Comment: While this is a very general question and rather opinion based, I'll just chime in and say that Solr is not (very) suitable for use as a general database. Its usage is primarily towards search, so "why not use both?" might be a viable solution.

Comment: Hello We will use elasticsearch through probably graylog for logging purpose and for operations support etc

Comment: @blacksensei elasticsearch, while providing some base databases usecases, is not a database. If you need database reliability and features, you can check Couchbase which natively integrates elasticsearch.

Comment: Hello @zenbeni thanks for your insight our usage of elasticsearch is purely for log management and not as per my usage description. Thanks for the suggestion though